# Mocking and unit testing implementation dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, mocking

I am trying to wrap my head around the practice of unit testing. I have read that unit tests should not be dependent on the implementations.

The way I understand this is, for example, if we have a function `int addTwoNumbers (int a, int b)` we should be testing whether, for example addition return correct results (i.e. `addTwoNumbers (2, 2) == 4)`) and we should not care whether, for example, `addTwoNumbers` calls `operator +` just once - it might as well use bit manipulation for this.

It seemed reasonable for me and - in my opinion - offers a decent decoupling between the tests and the code.

Enter the mocking frameworks. As far I can tell from reading their documentation, their functionality amounts to

(a) generating objects that implement placeholder functionality of some interfaces of base classes (stubbing) and

(b) checking whether that functionality was called according to expectations set forth by the tester.

I have no problems with (a) - I understand that we sometimes need to hard-code some functionality of external dependencies for the testing. I do not understand though, why should we check whether the tested code called mock's functionality in a way expected by the tester.

Shouldn't we be interested only in what a tested method returns or how it modifies its out arguments and not really care about its implementation details? Does the verification functionality of the mocking frameworks not introduce tight coupling between tested and testing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I do not understand though, why should we check whether the tested code called mock's functionality in a way expected by the tester

Because the contract of a method is not always to return something or to modify its arguments. Sometimes the contract of the method is (or includes) to have side effects. Think for example of the following method:

```
void notifyServerOfError(error: string) {
    this.http.post('/api/errors', {
        error: error,
        ip: myIpAddress
    });
}
```

This method doesn't return anything. It doesn't modify its arguments. Its sole responsibility is to send a specific object, containing specific details, to a specific URL. And unit-testing this method should thus verify that the contract is respected.

A good way to do that is to mock the `http` dependency and to check that, when this method is called, its `post()` method indeed being called with the correct URL and the correct data.